# pci-e x16 as input and usb 3.0 as output. Will it work?

Tags: conversion, pci-express, usb-3, adapter

I want to connect a [GTX 670 PCIe GPU](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-670) via USB 3.0 from a [Gigabyte Z77MX-D3H motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-Z77MX-D3H-rev-10/sp#sp) or a [Teclast X80 tablet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FMDUCDO) limited to USB output only. I think I possibly found the solution but I'm not sure if it's right solution. Here's [Device A](https://allegro.pl/oferta/adapter-przejsciowka-mini-pci-e-msata-do-usb-3-gdn-8199360343) and [Device B](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/USB-3-0-Mini-PCI-E_60658153949.html)

Can someone answer me would it work as I want if connected all together ?
If not then what's the right solution ?

Comment: @K7AAY, USB 3.1 and USB-C don't necessarily support external GPUs. Only a Thunderbolt 3 port & certified cable can connect PCIe lanes to an external GPU. Things get confusing because a Thunderbolt 3 port looks like Type-C and supports USB-C 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this will not work. There is no USB to PCI-e option.

What is out there is:

- PCI-e to PCI-e risers. Will give you a few centimeters, though I have seen a demo with very high quality cables succesfully running over longer lenghts.
  Pre-requisit is a PCI-e connection on your computer. Easy enough in any desktop. Almost centainly not found in a laptop. (and if you have a desktop just plug the card into one of the PCI-e slots in the desktop), so assuming you have a laptop. If not please explicityly mention it in your post).
- Same thing with mini PCI-e. This is what you have in link B.
  It starts with PCI-e, runs that over a cable which happens to be an USB3 cable because that is affordable and high enough quality. Note that is does NOT use USB protocol for this. Just the cable. It is a bit like running water though a gas line. It works, but it does not convert water to gas or vice versa.
  Then it exposes this PIC-e x1 signal in a physical PCI-e 16x external card. The last is probably so you can plug in any card without problems. But speed will still be limited to one (x1) PCI-e lane.
  That is fast enough to do some office work on, but not useful to add gamign speed to a laptop. (Once again, an assumption here. Maybe you only wanted a second or third screen on a laptop. In which case there are better solutions than an external PCI-e graphics card).
- Same thing can be done with some expresscard slots. Those tend to have one PCI-e lane and one USB connection.  For that you actually do not need fancy hacks.
- Then there is this nice shiny protocol for external PCI-e connection. Thunderbolt.  Thunderbolt-1, Thunderbolt-2 and Thunderbolt-3 all do that. TB3 is current and uses a physical plug that is mostly known as 'USB-C'. Most of the time that plug carries either USB 3, or thunderbolt. Note that just the form of the plug does not guarantee anything.

Answer (score 2):

No.

[Device A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075FR3ZD4) is a mSATA SSD Adapter To USB 3.0, Tanbin Mini SATA Use as Portable Flash Drive/External Hard Drive, 50mm Mini PCIe Solid State Drive Reader Converter. It will not output signals from a GPU, which eliminates the possibility of interfacing the tablet without tearing it open to find a true video output.

[Device B](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/USB-3-0-Mini-PCI-E_60658153949.html) lets you connect a PCIe x16 Video card into its slot. Device B  connects to a PCIe x1 slot in a desktop PC, if you happen to have one. There's also a power connector for Device B to draw power from the power supply of the desktop PC for the PCIe x16 video card. The power cable must be connected to work. However, the PCIe x16 video card will be limited by the interface to run at [x1 speed, 250 Mb/s output](https://www.anandtech.com/show/2973/6gbps-sata-performance-amd-890gx-vs-intel-x58-p55/2),  which is often very unsatisfactory; [PCI 3.0 x16 speed is 32 GB/s](https://www.trentonsystems.com/blog/pci-express-interface), so if you want full graphics card speed, this will not do what you want.

There are [external graphics adapters](https://www.displaylink.com/products/usb-adapters) which are USB-attached to a Windows PC, and [external graphics adapters which attach to a Thunderbolt 3 port](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NDZV2WC) (requiring a certified cable) for better performance.  The former will be significantly slower than the latter.